# Alternative to apply function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I would like to execute this simple transformation in a more efficient way.

```
df["amount"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: 500 if row.amount > 500 else row.amount, axis=1
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a sample data along with your expected output

Comment: `df['amount'] = df['amount'].clip(upper=500)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df["amount"].clip(upper = 500)
```

or [`numpy.clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```
np.clip(df["amount"], None, 500)
```

Comment: This is good. Have tried `np.clip(df['amount'].values, None, 500)`? I assume it will be faster

Answer (score 2):

You could also use np.where for maximum speed

```py
# assumes df['amount'] has no na, use .fillna(0) if needed
df["amount"] = np.where(df['amount'].values > 500, df['amount'].values, None)
```

Comment: this should be the top answer. np.where is fast and readable